Why my SBT (SoulboundToken-ERC721) code isn't displaying images on OpenSea?
Here's the code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract SoulboundToken is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint256 public constant MAX_SUPPLY = 20;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => bool) public hasMinted;
    mapping(address => bool) public eligibleVoter;

    string private baseTokenURI;

    constructor() ERC721("SoulboundToken", "SBT") {
        // Initialize baseTokenURI with correct IPFS URL format
        baseTokenURI = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QQmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww/";
    }

    function mintSoulbound() public {
        require(!hasMinted[msg.sender], "You have already minted your Soulbound token");
        require(_tokenIdCounter < MAX_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");

        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter;
        _tokenIdCounter += 1;

        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        hasMinted[msg.sender] = true;
        eligibleVoter[msg.sender] = true;

        totalSupply = _tokenIdCounter;
    }

    function isEligibleVoter(address _voter) public view returns (bool) {
        return eligibleVoter[_voter];
    }

    function hasMintedSoulbound(address _owner) external view returns (bool) {
        return hasMinted[_owner];
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override(ERC721) {
        require(from == address(0), "Token is soulbound and cannot be transferred");
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        // Concatenate baseTokenURI with tokenId and ".json"
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseTokenURI, tokenId.toString(), ".json"));
    }

    function setBaseTokenURI(string memory _baseTokenURI) external onlyOwner {
        baseTokenURI = _baseTokenURI;
    }
}


The cid (content-identifier) in your baseTokenURI is having an extra Q in the beginning, so instead of QQmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww, it should be QmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww.
So, the revised initialization line of baseTokenURI in the constructor should be:
baseTokenURI = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww/";

And, its content is:

Also, the tokenURI generated for the first minted token (i.e., having tokenId as 1) is:
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww/1.json

And, its content is:

In the JSON metadata, the URL corresponding to the image is:
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmWFLPa3K3cqX2gxwewRJcEfveiTwEeSHAggDvAc7xfvMM/1.jpg

But no image exists on that URL. Instead, an image named mint.jpg exists, which can be seen from the content of baseTokenURI, and its url should be:
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww/mint.jpg

Or, the same image exists on the url (by removing 1.jpg from the existing image URL) i.e.,
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmWFLPa3K3cqX2gxwewRJcEfveiTwEeSHAggDvAc7xfvMM

So, you need to change the URL of the image in the JSON metadata of your first tokenURI to either of these two, which means your revised 1.json can either be:
{
    "name": "Soulbound Token #1",
    "description": "This is a Soulbound Token that represents an eligible voter.",
    "image": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmZTwwzusZytzd9gUcA6rJmmcT359isFKSP26FNZF5N3Ww/mint.jpg",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Type",
            "value": "Soulbound"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Rarity",
            "value": "Rare"
        }
    ]
}

or:
{
    "name": "Soulbound Token #1",
    "description": "This is a Soulbound Token that represents an eligible voter.",
    "image": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmWFLPa3K3cqX2gxwewRJcEfveiTwEeSHAggDvAc7xfvMM",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "trait_type": "Type",
            "value": "Soulbound"
        },
        {
            "trait_type": "Rarity",
            "value": "Rare"
        }
    ]
}

In both the cases, you need to re-upload the data to IPFS, resulting in a new IPFS CID and thus a new baseTokenURI. Then, you need to use that baseTokenURI in your contract, and deploy the contract again.
